# Android NDK: override Application.mk compiler flags

Tags: c, android-ndk

Our project is written chiefly in pure C and has Application.mk with the following line:

```
APP_CFLAGS := -s -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-prototypes
```

But one of the modules is written in C++, so I get the following warning when this module is being compiled:

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' 
                 is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
```

That is global flags contain an item which can be used with gcc , but not g++. 
I am required to fix the warning.

I have tried to add local cpp flags to my module's Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -Wno-strict-prototypes
```

But it doesn't override global flags and I get the same warning.

Is there any way to get rid of this warning **without modifying Application.mk**?

Answer (score 2):

Use APP_CPPFLAGS to g++ flags insted of APP_CFLAGS.

```
APP_CPPFLAGS := -Wno-strict-prototypes
```